# Considering the linear system Ax=b, compute the rank and solve the general system.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A =
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1 & -2 & -2 & -2 \\
    3 & -2 & -2 & -2 & -2 \\
    -3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

and

b =

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    3 \\
    -1 \\
    -1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Since the matrix isn't square, it's not invertible, so I can't do inverse of A times b as in (x = A'b when Ax=b)

So how do I get the rank and solve it?

I thought rank could only be found on square matrices?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in an ouline how to solve:
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1 & -2 & -2 & -2 \\
    3 & -2 & -2 & -2 & -2 \\
    -3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\Rightarrow{-3R_1+R_2\rightarrow R_2 } \text{ and } { 3R_1+R_3\rightarrow R_3} \Rightarrow\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1 & -2 & -2 & -2 \\
    0 & 1 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
    0 & -1 & -5 & -5 & -7 \\
    \end{bmatrix}  \Rightarrow{R_2+R_3\rightarrow R_3}\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1 & -2 & -2 & -2 \\
    0 & 1 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

Now count the number of pivot. It is clear since there is no zero rows , so the rank is $3$.

Apply this same reduction process to the augmented matrix $[A | b ]$. You will have $x_4$ and $x_5$ as free variables  then $-x_3-x_4 -3 x_5=B_3$ where $B_3$ is the part the third component of $b$ after applying the row operations as above. Once you have $x_3$ follow the same process to get $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Edit:
Applying the same row reduction to $b$ you end up with $$\begin{bmatrix}3\\
-10\\
-2\end{bmatrix}$$
Thus  $-x_3-x_4 -3 x_5=-2\iff x_3=2-x_4-3x_5$.

$x_2+4x_3+4x_4+4x_5=-10\iff x_2=-10-4x_3-4x_4-4x_5$(now replace the value of $x_3$ from above).

$x_1-x_2-2x_3-2x_4-2x_5=3\iff x_1=3+x_2+2x_3+2x_4+2x_5 $ (now replace $x_2$ and $x_3$ from above to find $x_1$.

Here $x_4$ and $x_5$ can be anything and $x_1$ $x_2$ and $x_3$ are determined by what values of $x_4$ and $x_5$ you choose.

Comment: Hey thanks for the detailed response!
Wouldn't doing this for [A|b] lead to the same results but with 3, -10, -2 in the sixth column? I don't really understand what you mean to do after that as well.

Comment: @nr1 see the updated post for answer to your questions

Answer (score 0):

You can found the rank of the matrix even if the matrix non square. In general if A is a matrix of m rows and n columns, then the rank of A is smaller or equal than min(m,n).